# COpaquePointer to an arbitrary byte in a block of memory

Tags: c, pointers, swift

I'm porting some code to Swift, but I'm confused about how to handle pointers.

---

In Swift, **how do you create an empty block of memory, in such a manner that C functions can access it**?

*C source:*

```
UInt8* bytes = malloc( qty_bytes_in_file );
```

---

..and, after so-doing, **how would you create a pointer to an arbitrary offset of that memory**? I'll need to repeatedly move the pointers to various addresses in this block of memory, to which a C function will then write data.

*C source:*

```
void* mData = &bytes[i];
```

---

Here's an abbreviated version of the C code with which I'm starting, so you can see both lines in context:

*C source:*

```
UInt8* bytes = malloc( qty_bytes_in_file ); // Swift equivalent?

while ( !err ) {

    AudioBufferList buffer_list = new_buffer_list();

    buffer_list.mBuffers[0].mData = &bytes[i]; // Swift equivalent?

    // each iteration, ExtAudioFileRead fills 
    // in a portion of buffer_list's '.mData':
    err = ExtAudioFileRead(
        audio_file,
        &qty_frames_requested,
        &buffer_list
    );

    i += foo;

}
```

Comment: I would create an obj-c wrapper. Doing it in pure Swift will be just too difficult. However, your starting point is `UnsafePointer<UInt8>` which will enable you the `malloc` but as I see, you will have to also use a `reinterpretCast`.

Comment: @Sulthan Yes, I just finished writing a wrapper, you're totally correct. I think I read somewhere that Apple wants to discourage pointer arithmetic in Swift, since it causes a whole category of errors. The code would probably run slower in Swift anyways.

Comment: Useful example of making a buffer and filling it in, here: https://gist.github.com/rothomp3/0a7b9fef4249a4f91fc6

Answer (score 0):

For the first question I would just make an array of byte values:

```
var bytes = Array<UInt8>(count: qty_bytes_in_file, repeatedValue: 0)
```

And I think you can provide a reference to that array as an in-out parameter. For example:

```
let stream = NSInputStream(data: someNSDataObject)
let numberOfBytesRead = stream.read(&bytes, maxLength:buffer.count)
```

There is also in Swift a wrapper available …

```
struct UnsafePointer<T>
```

… with a "memory" property to get to the raw underlying memory.

Comment: My problem is slightly different. I need to do pointer arithmetic, e.g.: get a reference to the third or fourth byte in some malloced block of memory